# error: string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'

Tags: android

> I just Changed an Image and this Error pops out everytime. I am
>   unable to find for a solution, please provide your Information to
>   solve this.

```
 myTeacherModelLists.add(new MyTeacherModel(R.drawable.sets,"Settings"));
```

> Logcat :

```
 error: failed linking file resources.
```

> Model Class :

```
    package com.ionicframework.schoolzoneint;


public class MyTeacherModel {

    Integer images;
    String text;

    public MyTeacherModel(){

    }

    public MyTeacherModel(Integer images, String text) {
        this.images = images;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Integer getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: add some code and more explanation or people will start downvoting your post
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: add your MyTeacherModel code

Comment: added please check @yuvrajsinh